# AzureDevOp convey information from one stage to another using scripts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

[image: Pipeline]

I have a pipeline defined of two steps:

- one building a combined helm chart from two separate artifacts
- two deploying this chart to a cluster

Both stages first load a secret and then run a bash script to do the work, as shown in the following image.

[image: Steps]
My challenge now is, to submit the helm chart name and its version from the Build stage to the Deploy one. So that the 2 step can fetch the right chart.

How can I achieve this?

---

Trial 1: Using `##vso[task.setvariable` - Did not work from the script

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HELM_CHART_NAME]$HELM_CHART_NAME"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HELM_CHART_VERSION]$HELM_CHART_VERSION"
```

Comment: Try to share the variables with this tutorial: https://nganmenegay.com/2019/04/25/azure-devops-pipelines-set-release-variables-using-release-rest-api-so-that-their-values-will-persist-across-stages/

Comment: Stages should be independent of one another. Why do you need to do this as two stages?

Comment: Hi, how's the things going now? Does the below two method could help you achieve passing variables across stages?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT  I reverted to building everything from scratch so I avoid passing data

Comment: @lony Okay, but seems this would take longer time. If convenient, you can convert your solution as answer then accept it:-)

Answer (score 0):

> Using ##vso[task.setvariable - Did not work from the script

This caused by different stages using different agents, and the dynamic variable which set by  `##vso[task.setvariable` is just a **agent-scoped** one. Its life cycle equal with agent, so it will disappear once one agent job finished.

For the solution which can help you achieve pass variable from Build stage to Deploy stage, you'd better store these variables in one storage. Such as store it in Azure Key vault with the task [Azure Key Vault actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurekeyvault&targetId=3ec66d6c-317d-423e-a056-b014031f2871) or [Write Secrets to Key Vault](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cboroson.cboroson-WriteSecrets&targetId=3ec66d6c-317d-423e-a056-b014031f2871).

Another way is use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to add it as the release variable with powershell script:

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.0
```

Then, in next stage, it can access and get variable from Release Variables.

Comment: So there is no mechanism inside Azure DevOps?

Comment: @lony Until now, no. Because as the initially designed, the agent job should independent with each other. This is also what Daniel mentioned in comment. We offer storage as work around to let users can achieve some special cases, which like the second agent job need using one variable generated from the previous agent job.

Comment: Is it untypical to combine two artifacts to something new (aka a helm chart) and then deploy it to different stages? How can I then do this properly?

Comment: @lony Yes, it is typically. Most time we predefine these variables in Variables tab, then use them in the proper location. But also has limitation. In fact, there’s no any problem about your steps, just replace bash script as the method I mentioned in the answer: add the variable into azure key vault, or into release variables. Until now, limited by the independent agent job design, it could not achieve pass variable directly.

Comment: @lony We design it as independent just make sure that every deployment environment clearly, could not be affected by each other. But this has another disadvantages, which is you are facing. To achieve the new variable shared, must use one third party storage which can be accessed by all environment.